# Best Way to Read Pending Transactions of Uniswap on Ethereum 2.0 Blockchain

Tags: uniswap, pending-transactions, eth-2.0, stake

I am new to Ethereum2.0. I am trying to find a way to read transactions to Uniswap Pools. I looked at Alchemy, it seems they only allow subscribing pending transactions of one address.

So, I am looking for bring up a Node to use web3 to read the pending transactions. But I don't have 32ETH to stake, could I still use web3 to read pending transaction from Node without staking?

Comment: `could I still use web3 to read pending transaction from Node without staking` this is not possible with web3.js

Comment: There's no such thing known as Ethereum2.0. It is the same network it was before, just uses a different consensus algorithm.